# Orthogonalization - need correction

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

given are

$$v_1 = (i, \sqrt{2}i, -i)
,v_2 = (i, 0, -1)
,v_3 = (0, -i, \sqrt{2}i)$$

I need to calculate a orthogonalized basis and then norm then. I am not allowed to immediately use the orthonormalization of Gram Schmidt, I first have to to the orthogonalization of Gram Schmidt.

Here's what I did:

1.) I need Basis $B = (w_1, w_2, w_3)$

2.) $w_1 = v_1$

3.) $w_2 = v_2 - \frac{\langle w_1,v_2\rangle}{\langle w_1,w_1\rangle} \cdot w_1$

4.) $w_3 = v_3 - \frac{\langle w_1,v_3\rangle}{\langle w_1,w_1\rangle} \cdot w_1 - \frac{\langle w_2, v_3\rangle}{\langle w_2,w_2\rangle} \cdot w_2 $

I got the following results and somewhere must be a big mistake:

a) $ w_1 = v_1 $ is clear.

b) $\langle w_1, v_2\rangle = 2$ and $\langle w_1, w_1\rangle = 4$ so I have $w_2 = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} i \\ -i\sqrt{2} \\ -2+i \end{pmatrix}$

c) $\langle w_2, v_3\rangle = \sqrt{2} (1+i)$ and $\langle w_2, w_2\rangle = 2$
Together I have
$$w_3 = \frac{1}{4} \left[ \begin{pmatrix} 2i\sqrt{2} \\ 0 \\ 2i\sqrt{2} \end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix} i\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2} \\ 2 -2i \\ -3\sqrt{2} - \sqrt{2}i\end{pmatrix}\right]$$

I mentioned the complex-conjugation but I simply cannot find my mistake. There must be something wrong since they're not orthogonal =/

Comment: $\langle w_1,v_2\rangle=i\cdot(-i)+i\cdot 1 \ne 2$, not sure if there are other errors

Comment: You cannot use immediately G-S, you first have to... **what?**

Comment: Don't stress yourself with these names, "orthonormalization" consists of only one more step after "orthogonalization". I honestly don't know what happens in the head of some teachers. For Gauss's sake, they should focus first on the **ideas**, then on names.

Comment: Nice, a mathematical expletive. Thousand physicists and engineers!

Comment: Ok, I get it...but it's almost absurd: once one have an orthoghonal set (without zero) one only has to normalize each vector to get an orthonormal set...

Comment: Maybe he can't normalize the vector just after he found it. Doing this can simplify the calculations that follow, sometimes. But it's nonsense to impose that he should only normalize at the end.

Comment: You can simplify the vectors a bit while you are applying Gram-Schmidt to make your life easier before you normalize...you can multiply by constants as long as you are consistent with using the altered vectors for the remainder of the procedure. @Vazrael

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, it's really helpful! So @afedder I can change the orthogonalized vectors whenever I calculated one, if it's useful for further steps?

Comment: Yes, **as long as you are consistent** @Vazrael

Comment: Remember to keep track of what you have changed to be sure you're being consistent...if you multiply $v_2$ by a constant to use an altered vector, call that vector $v_2'$.

Comment: What exactly means consistent? That I have to use the new (altered) vector in any further steps? That I have to multiply the other basis-vectors by this constant as well?

Comment: No, just that you use $v_2'$ for all the remaining steps of Gram-Schmidt...you **don't** multiply every other basis vector by the constant. It's just a good idea to keep track of the changes you've made, so that you're aware. @Vazrael

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using the usual, Euclidean inner product, and then you have some mistakes:

$$\langle w_1,v_2\rangle=\left\langle(i,\sqrt2\,i,-i)\,,\,(i,0,-1)\right\rangle=-i^2+i=1+i\neq 2$$

so in fact

$$w_2=(i,0,-1)-\frac12(1+i)(i\,,\,\sqrt2\,i\,,\,-i)=\ldots$$